# FluentValidation: How does the automatic registration know which validator to use?

Tags: .net-core, fluentvalidation

I know that FluentValidation supports automatic validator registration like

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> 
{
  public CustomerValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Name).NotNull();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
  }
}
```

And in the startup.cs

`services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>()`;

But how does the automatic registration know which validator to use when you have multiple entities with corresponding validators like

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> 
{
  public CustomerValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Name).NotNull();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
  }
}
```

and

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> 
{
  public PersonValidator() 
  {
    RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(0, 10);
    RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
    RuleFor(x => x.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60);
  }
}
```

How does FlueentValidation know which validator to apply?

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple entities with corresponding validators" ? could you please elaborate

Comment: @CodingMytra - added the details in the question, please check

Comment: The type argument `T` of `AbstractValidator<T>` indicates which type should be validated.